# Search Results In a Drop List/Popup on Same Page

Tags: search

Does anyone have an example how I would implement search results that appear in a popup on the same form (without redirecting to a results page). The idea would be that as they start to type in the search bar, after a delay I'd show a popup with a few results.

I'm good on the jS, popup part. The part i don't know about is how i would call craft cms dynamically on the same page to get the results (would i do this with JS or with the form tag, can i make the request with JSON/Ajax?). All the examples show the form directing to a results page.

Anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can request any template via ajax using jQuery. jQuery would essentially listen for onChange events from the search field and ajax load a template that looped through the search results.

The template that you request can even be the default full search results page, with a conditional that determines which part of the template gets returned if the request is ajax.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

{% if not craft.request.isAjax %}
    {# Full page results content can go here #}
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <div class="search-results">
        <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if craft.request.isAjax %}
    {# Drop-down results can go here. And inserted into DOM via jquery. #}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

jQuery can then insert the results of the ajax call using an html element selector. See the jquery documentation for more information on using [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

You will also probably want to put the `{% set entries ... %}` inside the `if isAjax` statements so that you can limit the results, or implement pagination, for the drop down vs the full page.