# Javascript event on save for custom field

Tags: custom-fieldtype, custom-field, javascript

I have implemented a custom field type.

Is there any way to register a javascript event handler that is called before my custom field is saved?

Comment: Here is a full example of [intercepting a request via javascript](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/linking-to-search-results/4528#4528).

Answer (score 2):

Attach a submit event to the #entry-form element:

```
$('#entry-form').submit(function(e) {
    // code run on submit here
});
```